Internal SATA connection on my late 2014 27" iMac retina not visible in Windows 10 (my only OS partition)
I originally bought this Apple computer without the fusion drive and just a 256GB blade SSD.
Some years later I upgraded to a 1TB SSD (cloned from the original boot camp partitions).
While I was at it, I also bought a cheap aftermarket SATA cable and plugged in a new 2TB SATA SSD drive (which worked, for a time). More as additional storage as there aren't enough USB ports on this computer. Then one day, it, the SATA drive, stopped working. I could never solve the problem and started using the SATA SSD on an external USB enclosure instead.
Around this point I got rid of my Apple partition to give myself some more space on the main drive. I just never used it. It's still on the original SSD drive though in case I need it.
In case you are wondering, I could never adjust to the Apple operating system, I just preferred (or rather got used to using) Windows over the last ~35 years. Space was at a premium on the original 256GB unit.
Fast forward today. I upgraded the main blade SSD a second time. I took the opportunity to clean all the dust out (which was making the fan come on all the time).
Now I have a WD-Black SN850X NVMe 4TB internal SSD, which is working great! The whole upgrade process took much longer than expected, but at least it works. It should not be that difficult to swap out an SSD.
Anyway, I have since bought a large capacity Seagate Exos 16TB HDD drive to consolidate all my old files on. As they were all scattered around on about 5 or 6 smaller USB 3.0 external drives.
I had kind of assumed (or hoped) Windows would have fixed itself in the mean time.
Because sometimes it does. Driver issue maybe? But, alas it didn't.
Neither drive — the older 2TB SATA SSD or the Seagate Exos 16TB HDD — works on this SATA cable thing. Nothing appears in my computer or disk management other than the main blade SSD.
It doesn't make sense to get another bigger external enclosure for this meaty 16TB drive when I already have physical space in my machine. I don't like the external drives/enclosures that need a power supply, so I'm reluctant to get one of those. As it's another thing to plug in, plus taking up or rather swapping USB plugs/ports continuously.
Does anyone know if there is there any way I can get this big beast of a HDD working inside my now 10-year old trusty computer?
